# To get PHP communicate with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, database

**[My PHP code which I try to use in Firefox](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php)**

```
<?php
 // Connecting, selecting database
 $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=masi user=postgres password=abc")
     or die('Could not connect');
 ?>
```

I get

```
Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" in /var/www/ex1.php on line 3
```

The problem seems to be in my `/etc/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_hba.conf`.
It [seems that I need to add some ip-address to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745019/postgres-missing-or-erroneous-pghba-conf-file).

**Codes in my pg_dba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
 local   all         postgres                          ident sameuser
 
 # TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
 
 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
 local   all         all                               ident sameuser
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
 # IPv6 local connections:
 host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

The bug seems to be in PostgresSQL, since PHP and Apache2 work. I can access Psql by `sudo -u postgres psql`, since I have not managed to change the default settings. This is likely the cause of the problem. However, my PHP code uses the default settings so this should not be a problem.

I changed a line in my **/etc/apache2/envvars** unsuccessfuly:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=postgres     // I changed this line from masi to postgres
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid
```

I get the same error messages.

**How can you get the PHP work with PostgreSQL by pg_hba.conf in Ubuntu?**

Comment: Did you set a password to the user postgres ?

Comment: @Uka: I did not set any password initially. I removed the password from my code. I get a similar error message but with the message that `...to PostgreSQL server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied... `

Comment: Strange, I would think the third block (host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5) would work for what you want.

Comment: Please, move this question to Serverfault.com to solve the problem.

Comment: This thread is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### #1 problem

Log in to the user Postgres by

```
sudo su postgres
```

Create a new user, for instance, Masi for PostgreSQL by

```
 CREATE USER masi with SUPERUSER
```

Then, log in back to you default user.

### #2 problem

The default user in Pg has no password. This caused the problem in PHP.

I changed the `dbconn` to the following

```
 // independent variables
 $dbHost = "localhost";
 $dbPort = 5432;
 $dbName = "masi";
 $dbUser = "masi";
 $dbPassword = "your-password";

 $conn = "host=$dbHost port=$dbPort dbname=$dbName user=$dbUser password=$dbPassword";
```

The problem was the password of the default Postgres' account which I do not know.
This forced me to create a new account with a password.

I did not get pgAdmin 3 to work without a password in a database.

Comment: I strongly advise against using `WITH SUPERUSER` for application roles! If you have `root` access to the machine you can easily change the auth method of the postgres user in your `pg_hba.conf` file *temporarily*. Then, create a user for yourself using `md5` as auth method.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

or

```
local   all         all                               trust
```

[link text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: I run both your codes with and without a password in my PHP code unsuccessfully. I get the same error messages as before.

Comment: @andres-descalzo: It seems PHP does not support `trust` connections. I've been banging my head against the wall as well for the past 20 minutes... :(

Answer (score -5):

I solved the problem by adding the following line to `pg_dba.conf`.

```
# host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust #
```

Comment: FYI: This is being downvoted for two reasons: (a) it's commented out as written, so it has *no effect*, and (b) If you uncomment it it's dangerous: You are allowing ANYONE on the local system to connect to any Postgres database as any user (including the DB superuser) - you're one badly written PHP script away from someone using SQL injection to drop your production databases.